# Declaring an Array of dictionaries where the value for each key is another array (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, for-loop

I've looked at a few different posts on here and I cant seem to get what I'm specifically trying to do to work. I'm trying to declare an empty array of dictionaries. The problem is every time I try to iterate over each dictionary in the array(without running) I get an error basically saying that the way I set up the array isn't correct. This code is in my slide to delete function so it can't be run without the user populating the array of dicts first. Here is my code.

```
var leagueList = [Dictionary<String, Array<String>>]()


for dict in leagueList {

    let key = dict.key as String!

    if key == deletedAge {
        self.leagueList.removeValue(forKey: deletedAge!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Never mind, I may have read your question wrong.

Edit: I did

Comment: What's the error and what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: What are you expecting `dict.key` to do? Dictionaries can have more than one key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of things going on here.

You've properly declared `leagueList` as an array of dictionaries using generics. That's cool.

Your issues are:

1) `self.leagueList.removeValue(forKey: deletedAge!)` is looking for a key within an array. Arrays don't have keys, so you would get an error there.

2) `dict.key` appears to assume there is a single key in the dictionary. While `dict` is correctly a dictionary, Swift assumes it will have multiple keys. So, if you wanted to iterate through them (even if there's only one present) you'd have to use `dict.keys` instead.

If you're simply wanting to remove the `deletedAge` key's value for each dictionary in the `leagueList` array, an easy way to do that is:

```
var leagueList = [Dictionary<String, Array<String>>]()

for var dict in leagueList {
    dict.removeValue(forKey: deletedAge!)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been stuck on that for a while and it's funny that I was just really overthinking it the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to search through your array of dictionaries and remove a specific key from each one. To do that you need to use a two dimensional loop:

```
for var dict in leagueList {
    for key in dict.keys {
        if key == "someKey" {
            dict.removeValue(forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```